# C# WPF Получить в команде значение свойства

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

Есть такая команда для кнопки:

```
private RelayCommand addCommand;
    public RelayCommand AddCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return addCommand ??
              (addCommand = new RelayCommand(obj =>
              {
                  //Services.Insert(0, service);
                  //SelectedServices = service;
                  //MessageBox.Show(SelectedServices.Наименование_услуги.ToString());
              }));
        }
    }
```

Есть модель:

```
public class ServiceImport : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string serviceName;

    public string Наименование_услуги {
        get {return serviceName; }
        set
        {
            serviceName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Наименование_услуги");
        }
    }
    public string Главное_изображение { get; set; }
    public string Длительность { get; set; }
    public string Стоимость { get; set; }
    public string Действующая_скидка { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> С_учётом_скидки { get; set; }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string prop = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
    }
}
```

Каким образом я в команде могу получить значение "Наименование_услуги"?
Список услуг генерируется через ItemsControl и соответственно в каждой услуге есть кнопка "Редактировать" по нажатию на которую я должен получать название именно той услуги, на которой нажал кнопку

Класс RelayCommand:

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    private Action<object> execute;
    private Func<object, bool> canExecute;

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Func<object, bool> canExecute = null)
    {
        this.execute = execute;
        this.canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return this.canExecute == null || this.canExecute(parameter);
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        this.execute(parameter);
    }
}
```

Comment: В XAML пишете после привязки к команде `CommandParameter="{Binding}"`, тем самым весь объект у вас будет передан в команду в виде параметра. А дальше все зависит от реализации `ICommand`, ибо есть реализации где код будет как `EditCommand = new RelayCommand<ServiceImport>(Edit)`, а сам `Edit` - это простой метод `private void Edit(ServiceImport service){ // делаем дело... }`. В вашем же случае `obj`, это и будет ваш параметр (скорей всего типа `object`, а значит надо явно указать тип при работе с ним).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ возвращает null почему то, в команде написал так:
ServiceImport s = obj as ServiceImport;
MessageBox.Show(s.Наименование_услуги.ToString());

Comment: Автору рекомендую окунуться заново в теорию ООП, ваш вопросмвызван непониманием, как работает ООП. А технически вам выше верно подсказали. В xaml у кнопки `CommandParameter="{Binding}"` и внутри команды `ServiceImport service = obj as ServiceImport`. `service` в этом случае - то что вам нужно.

Comment: Если не работает - покажите в вопросе ваш класс `RelayCommand`.

Comment: @aepot показал класс RelayCommand

Comment: `RelayCommand` у вас в порядке, показывайте xaml кнопки и место, где вы привязываете `ItemsSource` вашего `ItemsControl`

Comment: @aepot а это же может быть связано с тем, что ItemsControl привязан к другой модели? Ахахахх

Comment: @aepot вообще у меня модель автоматически сгенерирована фреймворком Entity, но я там не могу вручную что-то дописывать и поэтому не знаю как работать с этой же моделью

Comment: Все может быть. Я же не вижу ваш проект. Но вы сначала поразбирайтесь как следует, а потом задавайте вопросы. Здесь нет магии, все работает весьма очевидным образом. И избавьтесь от кириллицы в названиях свойств и полей: во-первых ваш код невозможно читать, во-вторых оно может вызвать непредсказуемые проблемы.

Comment: @aepot да, дело было в модели, что я обращался не к настоящей, а своей зачем-то выдуманной, теперь он всё правильно получает, по поводу ООП понял, буду его тщательно учить и спасибо за подсказки

Comment: По моделям, модель - это данные, вам не надо туда что-то дописывать, вам нужно написать вью-модель, которая умеет эти данные оттуда в себя загружать, и туда сохранять. Дописывать надо именно во вью-модель, а не в модель. Поэтому и шаблон программирования называется MVVM: модель - данные, вью - интерфейс, и вью-модель - представление данных для интерфейса.

Comment: @aepot дошло, ещё раз благодарю, хоть глаза раскрылись немного, мне теперь в текстбоксе нужно это название услуги отобразить, я знаю что это другой вопрос, но если вкратце, то нужно в текстбоксе сделать привязку к свойству этой услуги?

Comment: Ну да, просто `Text="{Binding Свойство}"`.